# How to deteriminate max string length in on line in edit box in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I was wondering how can i make that when user input longer string than box's width cursor goes to a new line and when there is more text that can fit into editbox, showbar shows itself and user can input 'infinite' lenght string?

Comment: Use a memo control for multi line text

Comment: Can you give me and en example pls ?

Comment: No example needed. Drop a memo control onto your form.

Comment: I tried using memobox but when i type more text then memo width end hight can store first line of text just disapear from visible part of memo box, and scroll bar dont shows up. How can i make that ? Sry for my stupid Q but i just started using Lazarus for my scool.

Comment: There's no such thing as memobox. You mean TMemo? Don't be sloppy with details. Did you set the WordWrap property?

Comment: I was thinking about tmemo sry. I will try that thanks for idea xD

Comment: Your title does not match your question. As David said, drop a TMemo on the form, set the WordWrap property to True, change the Scrollbars property to include `ssVertical`, and size the memo control to the space you want it to use on your form.